# R lazy evaluation paradox (R bug?)

Tags: r, promise, lazy-evaluation

I have multiple functions handing around arguments that may be missing.

e.g. i have

```
mainfunction <- function(somearg) {
    mytest(somearg)
    fun <- function() { subfunction(somearg) }
    fun()
}
```

with the interesting aspect that the only interaction of `mytest(somearg)` with the arg is that it tests if the argument isn’t missing:

```
mytest = function(somearg) {
    print(missing(somearg))
}
```

`subfunction` then again tests if it’s missing and treats it accordingly:

```
subfunction = function(somearg) {
    if (missing(somearg))
        somearg = NULL
    else
        somearg = matrix(somearg, cols = 2)
    # somearg is used here…
}
```

the kicker is that, with `somearg` missing, this doesn’t work: `matrix(somearg, cols = 2)` throws

> argument "somearg" is missing, with no default

during debugging, i found the following:

1. at the start of `mainfunction`, `missing(somearg)` returns `TRUE`
2. in `mytest`, `missing(somearg)` returns `TRUE`
3. in`subfunction`, `missing(somearg)` returns `FALSE` (!!!!)

therefore the `matrix` branch is hit, but in reality, `somearg` *is* missing, so it fails…

wat.

Comment: I’m guessing that the problem here is that you don’t call `subfunction` directly, but rather from a nested function, which creates a closure over the argument `somearg`. It seems closures cannot treat missing arguments. I’m unsure whether this is a bug or “by design”: inside `fun`, `somearg` is **not** an argument, it’s a normal variable, and hence cannot be missing.

Comment: See the documentation: "Currently `missing` can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a `local` call."

Comment: with “can only be used” meaning “it will behave completely unexpected elsewise”. damn. thanks.

Comment: While `missing` is nice, I find it much easier to pass `NULL` as an explicit missing value in these kinds of situations; it makes the function documentation marginally uglier, but there's never any problem like this with testing `is.null(arg)`.

Comment: @BenBolker yeah, that’s what i ended up using. thanks! (it also makes clear that there is a meaningful default just by glancing at the function signature)

Comment: @rawr undefined behavior like this isn’t necessarily a technical bug, but certainly a usability bug. R is an easy-to-use language for statistics, not something like C where you have 300 machineguns all pointed at your foot simultaneously. so i’d argue “missing(something)” returning “FALSE” and trying to use it throwing an “argument missing” error *within the same scope* is a bug.

Comment: btw, @BenBolker if you combine what i did wrong and how to circumvent it in a short answer i’m happy to make the checkmark :D

Comment: or @Roland, of course (but i can only mention one person in a comment(‽))

Answer (score 1):

the @BenBolker way:

```
mainfunction <- function(somearg = NULL) {
    mytest(somearg)
    fun <- function() { subfunction(somearg) }
    fun()
}

mytest = function(somearg) {
    print(is.null(somearg))
}

subfunction = function(somearg) {
    if (is.null(somearg))
        somearg = 1:10
    else
        somearg = matrix(somearg, ncol = 2)
   somearg
}
```

Another way, using explicit missing argument

```
mainfunction <- function(somearg) {
    is_missing <- missing(somearg)
    mytest(is_missing)
    fun <- function() { subfunction(somearg, is_missing) }
    fun()
}
mytest = function(x) {  print(x) }
subfunction = function(somearg, is_arg_missing) {
    if (is_arg_missing)
        somearg = 1:10
    else
        somearg = matrix(somearg, ncol = 2)
   somearg
}
```

A third way, using plain missing arg passing:

```
    mainfunction <- function(somearg) {
        is_missing <- missing(somearg)
        mytest(somearg)
        fun <- function() { 
          if (is_missing) subfunction() else 
              subfunction(somearg) 
        }
        fun()
    }

    mytest = function(somearg) {
        print(missing(somearg))
    }

    subfunction = function(somearg) {
        if (missing(somearg))
            somearg = 1:10
        else
            somearg = matrix(somearg, ncol = 2)
       somearg
    }
```